# Laravel installed in Digital ocean and want to add a worpress blog on the same subdoamin

Tags: wordpress, laravel, blogs, digital-ocean

I have a laravel project hosted in Digital Ocean as(www.example.com) in a droplet. I would like to have a wordpress blog as(www.example.com/blog) subdomain with the laravel Project.

---

In order to get rid of the the public directory in url, I moved all the files of ***public*** directory into ***html*** and all the folders and file of ***html*** into another folder named as ***local*** in html directory. 
I unzipped the wordpress files inside the var/www/html/blog directory.
But I am not able to setup the Wordpress.

This is how I get when I move into the url: www.example.com/blog

[image]

Comment: The url you want to use is not a subdomain it is just a directory. I should go with a real subdomain like blog.example.com. There are many reasons for this think about seo, version control, deployment, scalability.

Comment: not to mention the plethora of conflicts than may arise from having WP (which needs custom htaccess or nginx configs for URL rewriting, etc) with Laravel (who manages routes in a different way) trying to coexist in the same place... it can be done, but it can be a pain

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your database information to the wp-config.php file. [See this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)